# weird behavior scope and ng-repeat in view, angular JS

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having a weird behavior.

In the view I have the follow code :

```
<div class="form-group">

  <select class="form-control" name="name" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="selectedOption">
    <option ng-repeat="o in availableOptions" value="{{o}}">{{o.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
<p>{{selectedOption}}</p>
<p>{{selectedOption.value}}</p>
```

And in the controller I have :

```
$scope.availableOptions= [
  {id: '1', name: 'name2', value:{w: 100, h: 250}},
  {id: '2', name: 'name1', value:{w: 200, h: 100}},
  ];
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.availableOptions[1];
```

The problem is the follow : At first time the first two `<p>` (selectedOption and selectedOption.value) are showing right. However when I change the value of in the select only `<p>{{selectedOption}}</p>` is showed while `<p>{{selectedOption.value}}</p>` doesn't show anything.

Any help???

PD: with ng-option into select it worked, but why with ng-repeat not?

Comment: Can you provide some output code or console logs please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only explanation I could think of was that it changes the object into a string. The work around you could do is creating `ng-change="foo(selectedOption)"` into the select and the function looking something like this:

```
$scope.foo = function(val){
     $scope.selectedOption = angular.fromJson(val);   
}
```

## EDIT

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp from here we can confirm that the value is converted to string.

Comment: Yes it will work, but it is not the best solution for this. Do you know what this behavior ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp from here you can see that value tag returns a text value. This is the reason why you won't get the `{{selectedOption.value}}` working because it's returning a string.

Comment: You are right, the problem is that {{selectedOption.value}} return a string. So the best option that I have chosen  is use "ngSelect".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value attribute to:

```
<div class="form-group">

  <select class="form-control" name="name" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="selectedOption">
    <option ng-repeat="o in availableOptions" ng-value="o.value">{{o.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
<p>{{selectedOption}}</p>
<p>{{selectedOption.value}}</p>
```